# React component doesn't render content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, babeljs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Imprint.scss';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import ContentSection from '../ContentSection';
import axios from 'axios';
import { IMPRINT_URL } from '../../auth_axios';

class Imprint extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imprintText: null,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchImprint();
  }
  render() {
    const {
      imprintText
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <section className="bsl-imprint row">
        <ContentSection>
          <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h2 className="bs-main-heading">Imprint</h2>
            <p>
              <ReactMarkdown source={imprintText}/>
            </p>
          </div>
        </ContentSection>
      </section>
    );
  }
  fetchImprint() {
    axios.get(IMPRINT_URL)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        this.setState({imprintText: res.data})
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}

export default Imprint;
```

I'm using React 15.4, Redux 3.7, with Babel to render some text. So I'm trying to render **imprintText** on the *ReactMarkdown* tag inside a component, but it's displaying plain HTML code instead of the content. I provide an screenshot to show you how it looks. Any ideas??

[SCREEN_SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG9Qm.png)

Comment: I think  imprintText is taken as string. convert into a valid html before using. Try that

Comment: @stack26 No. ReactMarkdown requires `source` prop as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 'imprintText' is **string** you have to do in the following way,

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.imprintText}}
```

eg:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.imprintText }} />
```

Comment: Great! do you know any good documentation for **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** ?? Thanks Mate!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml from react documentation itself.

Answer (score 1):

According to [react-markdown docs](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown#options), you have to set the `escapeHtml` prop to `false`, so that the `<ReactMarkdown>` component renders HTML as well, i.e.:

```
<ReactMarkdown source={imprintText} escapeHtml={false}/>
```

It's [not generally recommended to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). Besides, I think your `imprintText` doesn't need all the `<head>` and `<body>` tags, just the `<div>` tag onwards would suffice.